# Map multiple request parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm sending two parameters using GET (through URL) and I would like my request method to receive them like this...

Here's the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/basketItems")
public String basketItems(
    @RequestParam("fname") String firstName, 
    @RequestParam("lname") String lastName, 
    Model model) {

    Customer customer = customerManager.getCustomer(firstName, lastName);
    Basket basket = basketManager.getBasket(customer.getReferenceNumber());

    model.addAttribute("basket", basket);
    model.addAttribute("totalItems", basketManager.getTotalNumberOfItems(basket));
    model.addAttribute("totalPrice", basketManager.getTotalProductPrice(basket));

    return "basketItems"; 
}
```

I get this error

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:Required java.lang.String parameter 'lname' is not present
```

Comment: please format you sample code

Answer (score 5):

Your HTTP request doesn't have the parameter `lname` present. Either include that parameter in the request, or put `required = "false"` on the annotation for `lname`:

```
@RequestParam(value="lname", required="false")
```

If you put `required = "false"`, then the variable assigned to `lname` will be `null` in that method, so be aware of that in your code.

For some more information, look at the relevant part of the [**Spring MVC documentation**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam).

Answer (score 0):

What is your request URI?

MissingServletRequestParameterException is thrown because there is no request parameter of type String with name lname to bind to variable lastName